# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error laravel 5.2 on asp.net server

Tags: php, laravel-5, fastcgi

I am uploading my project laravel 5.2 in asp.net hosting, it's work .. but if I refresh the web page I have this error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error 
>    c:\php55\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly**

But if I refresh again it's work, also if I use laravel version 4.2 it's work well without this error.

My project link : http://lapchecks-001-site1.ftempurl.com/blog/public/

Comment: Verify the PHP and web server error logs, after making sure that your PHP configuration enables error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

That happen in laravel 5.2 project and not 4.2 projects because the new version use php version 5.5 and since you're using php 5.5 (`c:\php55..`) Visual c++ redistributable for visual studio 2012 is required for it so make sure that the **[VC++11 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)** is well installed and the problem will disappear.

Hope this helps.